# Insert API-returned <script> into Meteor template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, embedly

I'm using embedly and I want to insert the html returned into a template. Most of the time it works but if the html has a `script` tag then Meteor doesn't render it and everything falls apart. Anyway around this?

Comment: Is the script tag a script element containing script or is it a script element linking to a script document? (Local code or remote code)

Comment: Remote code. Example: <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>